# Hardware breakpoints can only be set at module initialization

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, breakpoints, kernel-module

I would like to use `register_wide_hw_breakpoint` in my kernel module to observe changes to the page structs of the memory pages I am working with (for debugging purposes).
However, it seems like I can only register breakpoints in the module init function. The function returns -1 (EPERM?) if I use it from the ioctl-handler. [This blogpost](https://martin.uy/blog/hardware-breakpoints-in-the-linux-kernel-through-perf_events/) had me assume it should be possible.

I am running a *5.1.0* kernel on a *Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4215*.

Example code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>

static uint32_t val = 0;
void inc_val(void)
{
        val++;
}

struct perf_event * __percpu *sample_hbp;

static void sample_hbp_handler(struct perf_event *bp, struct perf_sample_data *data, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
        pr_info("My module: val changed!");
}

int test_hw_breakpoint(void)
{
        struct perf_event_attr attr;
        hw_breakpoint_init(&attr);

        attr.bp_addr = (unsigned long)&val;
        attr.bp_len = HW_BREAKPOINT_LEN_4;
        attr.bp_type = HW_BREAKPOINT_W;

        pr_info("My module: HW breakpoint at 0x%llx\n", attr.bp_addr);
        sample_hbp = register_wide_hw_breakpoint(&attr, sample_hbp_handler, NULL);
        if (IS_ERR((void __force *)sample_hbp))
        {
                int ret = PTR_ERR((void __force *)sample_hbp);
                pr_info("My module: Breakpoint registration failed: %d\n", ret);
                return ret;
        }

        inc_val();
        pr_info("My module: val: %d", val);
        inc_val();
        pr_info("My module: val: %d", val);

        unregister_wide_hw_breakpoint(sample_hbp);

        return 0;
}

static int mod_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        (void)inode;
        (void)file;
        pr_info("My module: Opening...\n");

        return 0;
}

static int mod_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        (void)inode;
        (void)file;
        pr_info("My module: Releasing...\n");

        return 0;
}


static long mod_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned num, uintptr_t param)
{
        (void)file;
        (void)num;
        (void)param;

        pr_info("My module: Ioctl...\n");

        test_hw_breakpoint();

        return 0;
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
        .open = mod_open,
        .release = mod_release,
        .unlocked_ioctl = mod_ioctl,
};

static struct miscdevice mod_dev = {
        .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
        .name = "mymod!io",
        .fops = &fops,
        .mode = 0666,
};

int mod_init(void)
{
        int ret;

        ret = misc_register(&mod_dev);
        if (ret != 0)
                return ret;

        test_hw_breakpoint();

        return 0;
}

void mod_exit(void)
{
        misc_deregister(&mod_dev);
}

static int __init od_init(void)
{
        int ret;
        pr_info("My module: Initializing...\n");

        ret = mod_init();
        if (ret != 0)
                return -1;

        return 0;
}

static void __exit od_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("My module: Terminating...\n");
        mod_exit();
}

module_init(od_init)
module_exit(od_exit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Produces the following output in dmesg:

```
[  +0.031269] My module: Initializing...
[  +0.000086] My module: HW breakpoint at 0xffffffffc04ae4c8
[  +0.000191] My module: val changed!
[  +0.000002] My module: val: 1
[  +0.000003] My module: val changed!
[  +0.000001] My module: val: 2
[  +0.002405] My module: Opening...
[  +0.000003] My module: Ioctl...
[  +0.000003] My module: HW breakpoint at 0xffffffffc04ae4c8
[  +0.000019] My module: Breakpoint registration failed: -1
[  +0.000003] My module: Releasing...
```

I don't know the memory address to observe at module initialization. Is there any way I can add a data breakpoint at runtime?

Comment: The process that is calling `ioctl` probably does not have privileges to set hardware breakpoints. Try running it with `sudo`.

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott, thanks for the tip!
Running the calling process with sudo indeed solved the problem.
I don't understand why though. I would expect that when switching into kernel context, the privileges of the caller don't matter anymore.
Could you please elaborate on this a little more? If you do it in an answer, I'll mark it as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a process issues a system call, it switches to kernel mode, but the kernel code is running in "process context". The process could, in theory, do anything while running in kernel mode. However, typical kernel code will check that the calling process has the capability to do what it is trying to do. A process has a list of capabilities of things it is allowed to do: see [capabilities(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities).

In OP's particular case, the unprivileged process that is issuing the `ioctl` call that results in the call to `register_wide_hw_breakpoint` is probably failing when it fails the check in the `hw_breakpoint_parse` function in "kernel/events/hw_breakpoint.c":

```
    if (arch_check_bp_in_kernelspace(hw)) {
        if (attr->exclude_kernel)
            return -EINVAL;
        /*
         * Don't let unprivileged users set a breakpoint in the trap
         * path to avoid trap recursion attacks.
         */
        if (!capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
            return -EPERM;
    }
```

Comment: Capabilities was the magic word. Googling for "ioctl" & "privileges" only produced unhelpful stuff...
Thanks again!